# Yii-user: send activation mail

Tags: email, yii, php

I've implemented the yii-user module in a new php project and everything works fine. But when i register, the program should sent an activation email , but when i press the register button i get the following error:

> mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at >"localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting     >in php.ini or use ini_set()

I've searched and i changed my ini file to:

```
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 465 
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = xxxxxxx@gmail.com
```

But that didn't help.

How do i solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by just installing and running this little program : http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/

This program sits in the system tray and does not deliver the received messages and the webapp runs just fine!

Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It seems your problem is that Gmail is not an open relay, meaning it requires authentication with an account in order to accept outgoing mail. See the Gmail page [Problems sending mail](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78775). At the very least, you'll need to supply account information, and I don't see that in your example.

Comment: Wel i've found [this](http://digiex.net/guides-reviews/guides-tutorials/application-guides/544-configuring-php-under-windows-use-gmail-external-smtp-server-ssl.html) tutorial. And i followed it, so i gave in my account information etc. I also activated smtp in my gmail settings. But it still doesn't work. Does anyone know a good email extension for the yii framework to use in combination with yii-user?

Comment: At this point I would recommend testing with an email server of your own configured on some other machine (perhaps virtual). It would be useful to divide the problem between email service configuration and something else, whatever that might be.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your hosting services is blocking port 465

Comment: What do you mean? the site is running under localhost with wamp.

Comment: That information was not in your OP. Sometimes hosting companies block port 465 for outgoing connections. It's also possible that a local network's firewall could have blocked outgoing ports. Even if this is not the problem in your case, it could be the issue for someone else.

Comment: Also google smtp required authorization, but mail not able do it (IMHO)